# ModelForm has no model class specified while accessing to html

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model form and shown the error: ModelForm has no model class specified while accessing to html.

forms.py:

```
class Add_Product(forms.ModelForm):
product_name = forms.CharField()
price = forms.DecimalField()
img = forms.ImageField()
img2 = forms.ImageField()
img3 = forms.ImageField()
storage_amount = forms.IntegerField()
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}))
Hot = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES)
status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS)
slug = forms.CharField()

class Meta:
    models = Product
    fields = ('product_name', 'price', 'img', 'img2', 'img3', 'storage_amount', 'description', 'Hot', 'type', 'status', 'slug')
```

views.py:

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Add_Product(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Succeed')
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = Add_Product()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'add_product.html', context)
```

add_prodcut.html:

```
<form method="POST" class="card-body" >
          {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form | crispy }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show your `Product` model in your *models.py* please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Meta:
    models = Product
```

Should be

```
class Meta:
    model = Product
```